# Create mirror Tables in Excel

Tags: excel

I need to create two mirror tables in my sheet. With "mirror" I mean that they will have exactly the same values (at least in the column I need) and whatever changes I do to the one will automatically be transferred to the other e.g. when I insert a row in Table1 it will automatically insert a row in Table2.

I have tried doing that with the "Relationships" option, VLOOKUP but none of these worked. Hardcoding the range with relative reference is also not a solution as I need to keep my table clear of blank cells. Finally, it would be ideal not to use a macro for that but I will not turn down a solution that includes one.

Does anyone know if this is doable and have any idea on how to do it? Thank you!

Comment: Your choices are functions or a macro....unless everytime you make a change you have the choice of CTRL+A > CTRL+C *select new sheet* CTRL+V and paste values.

Comment: Or copying the whole sheet.

Comment: Guys, I never said I don't want a function. I said that the functions I tried didn't work. And I would prefer not to use a Macro for security reasons. My main issue is how will the data be transferred from one table to the other when I add new rows to it

Comment: @pnuts what do you mean group the two sheets?